# Is LIMIT x, y absolutely equivalent to OFFSET x LIMIT y in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm mostly posting this question as a resource for others as I couldn't find anything explicitly answering it online: Is the `LIMIT x,y` syntax performatively equivalent to `OFFSET x, LIMIT y`?

According to official [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html):

> For compatibility with PostgreSQL, MySQL also supports the LIMIT row_count OFFSET offset syntax.

This implies to me that they are absolutely equivalent.

But I can't find any official doc saying so explicitly. So I'm 99% sure there aren't any low level differences, but would love that official stamp of approval and peace of mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually wasn't sure, and I can't find any documentation either, but I tested it and it seems to work just fine.  Results:

```
andrew@uf ~ $ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.66, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
...

mysql (sandbox) > SELECT * FROM db1.t1 LIMIT 1, 2;
+-------+------------+-----------------------------+
| grpID | grpCode    | grpDesc                     |
+-------+------------+-----------------------------+
|     2 | INTL_LEADS | International leads         |
|     3 | CPE_LEADS  | CPE-specific Domestic leads |
+-------+------------+-----------------------------+

mysql (sandbox) > SELECT * FROM db1.t1 LIMIT 2 OFFSET 1;
+-------+------------+-----------------------------+
| grpID | grpCode    | grpDesc                     |
+-------+------------+-----------------------------+
|     2 | INTL_LEADS | International leads         |
|     3 | CPE_LEADS  | CPE-specific Domestic leads |
+-------+------------+-----------------------------+
```

So yeah.  I did more testing than this, but I don't want to post all of it.  That's pretty handy to know as that syntax makes more sense to me.

Comment: Yep, they're functionally equivalent (produce the same results), but I'm curious to know whether low level stuff, ie memory allocation and bytecode order is identical.

Comment: @BrianDuncan I'm not sure but the query plan is the same

Comment: This appears to be the case of supporting two different notation styles with the same effect, comparable to the difference between `INSERT INTO x (y) VALUES (z)` and `INSERT INTO x SET y=z`.

Comment: @tadman `SET` only lets you insert one row whereas you can insert many with `VALUES`